# How can I prevent the Cesium ion logo from showing up?

Tags: cesiumjs

Using [Cesium Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html), if I have:

HTML body & css

```
<style>
  @import url(../templates/bucket.css);
</style>
<div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
<div id="loadingOverlay"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
<div id="toolbar"></div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
const osm = new Cesium.OpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
  url : 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/'
});


const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
  baseLayer: Cesium.ImageryLayer.fromProviderAsync(osm),
  baseLayerPicker: false,
  geocoder: false,
  creditContainer: null,
  creditViewport: null,
});
```

It is my understanding that I should not be using Cesium ion. Is this correct?

However, what appears in the window contains the logo and text for Cesium ion:

[image: Cesium ion logo]

I assume I am missing some configuration option that would allow me to either not show the logo or have it show the correct one which just says "Cesium" or something.

I thought that adding the lines:

```
  creditContainer: null,
  creditViewport: null,
```

would hide it. I don't see any other obvious configuration options.

If hiding it isn't an option, then having it show just `Cesium` or `CesiumJS` would be preferred over `ion`, which I am not using.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CesiumJS requires some extra steps to be fully offline and independent from Cesium ion according to their [documentation](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/tree/main/Documentation/OfflineGuide).

As far as removing the Cesium Ion logo, you can use the following JS code or CSS code to remove:

**JS**:

```
viewer._cesiumWidget._creditContainer.parentNode.removeChild(
viewer._cesiumWidget._creditContainer);
```

or

```
viewer._cesiumWidget._creditContainer.style.display = "none";
```

**CSS**:

```
.cesium-widget-credits{
display:none !important;
}
```

**Please note:**
While it is technically possible to remove the Cesium logo, doing so while using Cesium ion services is against the terms of service. (see [Cesium Terms of Service](https://cesium.com/legal/terms-of-service/))

Source: [Cesium Forum Post](https://community.cesium.com/t/cesium-ion-logo-removal/8979)

**EDIT**

Voted best by the questioner, you can also make the following change to the original code:

```
const osm = new Cesium.OpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
  url : 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/'
});


const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
  baseLayer: Cesium.ImageryLayer.fromProviderAsync(osm),
  baseLayerPicker: false,
  geocoder: false,
  creditContainer: document.createElement("none")
});
```

Comment: Would `creditContainer: null,` not removing the logo be considered a bug? It seems like it should.

Comment: According to [link](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Viewer.html) the wiki for creditContainer, "The DOM element or ID that will contain the CreditDisplay. If not specified, the credits are added to the bottom of the widget itself." sounds like assigning the property to null it is intended behavior as you're not specifying it correctly. If you modify your code to say `creditContainer: document.createElement("none")` it should work as you're imagining in the original post. @EricG

Comment: Using `document.createElement("none")` worked well. That does seem like the best solution over those changes to viewer and the additional CSS. Can you add it to the answer? I think it would help so others would not need to scan through the comments to find it.

Comment: The old Cesium and Desist method.